# Regression methods for indicator function as covariate

Tags: regression, frequentist, indicator-function

I am looking for a regression method to fit the following model:
$$Y=\beta_0 + \beta_1X+\beta_2 I(X>\beta_3)X + \varepsilon,$$
where $\varepsilon \sim N(0, \sigma^2)$, and $I$ is the indicator function. This means:
\begin{equation}
  Y =
    \begin{cases}
      \beta_0 + \beta_1X & \text{if } X\leq \beta_3\\
      \beta_0 + \beta_1X + \beta_2X& \text{if } X > \beta_3\\
    \end{cases}       
\end{equation}

I can specify this model within the Bayesian framework. However, I am not aware of any regression method within frequentist approach that I can fit this model (possibly in a package in R).

Comment: Search our site for "structural change" and "change-point."